# mysql left join produces fewer results than expected

Tags: mysql, left-join

There are a number of [left join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680078/mysql-left-join-not-producing-expected-results) questions already, but still I can't quite put my finger on this issue.  The WHERE condition doesn't look sensible to move.

The problem is that there should be 4 rows returned but only 1 is.

In checking the left join conditions, there is 1 row returned for each left join, which is correct for the number of records in the table, however the query below returns 1 record instead of 4, but I can't see how to return 4, yet.

**Query follows:** (Gives 1 result not 4; 4 being expected)

```
SELECT 
 list.uid,
 list.business_uid,
 list.creator_name,
 business.company_name,
 list_alias.uid AS list_alias_uid,
 list_alias.alias AS list_alias,
 list_member.uid AS list_member_uid,
 mailbox.full_name AS list_member_name,
 mailbox.email_address AS list_member_email_address
FROM
 mailbox,
 business,
 list
LEFT JOIN
 list_alias ON list_alias.list_uid=list.uid
LEFT JOIN
 list_member ON list_member.list_uid=list.uid
WHERE
 list.business_uid='1'
 AND list.business_uid=business.uid
 AND mailbox.uid=list_member.mailbox_uid
ORDER BY
 list.full_name ASC
```

**Data:**

*Business UID 1 has 4 lists*

`SELECT * FROM list WHERE business_uid=1` -- gives 4 results

`SELECT * FROM list_alias WHERE list_uid IN (SELECT uid FROM list WHERE business_uid=1)` -- gives 1 result

`SELECT * FROM list_member WHERE list_uid IN (SELECT uid FROM list WHERE business_uid=1)` -- gives 1 result

Any pointers on what I could check would be welcome.

**Table Sample Data:**

list:

```
uid | business_uid | creator_name | full_name
--------------------------------------------------
 1          1         List Maker   Subscribe to W
 2          1         List Maker   Subscribe to X
 3          1         List Maker   Subscribe to Y
 4          1         List Maker   Subscribe to Z
```

business:

```
uid | company_name
-------------------
 1    List Company
```

list_alias:

```
uid | list_uid | alias
----------------------------------------
 1       1       subscriber@list-url.com
```

list_member:

```
uid | list_uid | mailbox_uid
------------------------------------
 1       1       1
```

mailbox:

```
uid | full_name | email_address
-------------------------------
 1     I am He    me@me.com
```

Comment: Please, **don't blend join flavours**. See this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11180050/1291428 Your query might not be the one you think it is.

Comment: what about `mailbox` and `business` do they contain enough data to support the 4 rows?

Comment: when joining mailbox and list_member, there is a single record matching the list_member and when joining to business, there is only 1 match to the business_uid=1 condition, so there are appropriate entries in both those tables when separately checked.  Removing the LEFT JOINS conditions in the above query (and related conditions) results in the correct 4 lists showing.

Comment: @MyStream Do you mind if I edit your question to change the old-fashioned implict join syntax?  That's what Sebas is referring to and that by itself might make your answer obvious.

Comment: @BellevueBob - please - anything that helps readability/better syntax will be of benefit. I am not following where to make a change based on Sebas's comment. Any clues?

Comment: Can you provide sample data (better in the form of a sqlfiddle)?

Comment: @MyStream I can't see the relation to all your tables.  The "comma" syntax you are using is doing an INNER JOIN; the WHERE clause should show the relation but I don't see it for your `business` table.  Change those commas to "ON" conditions and provide the common columns.

Comment: It would be easier if you added the five table descriptions to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using a single join methodology, like so.

```
SELECT list.uid,
    list.business_uid,
    list.creator_name,
    b.company_name,
    la.uid AS list_alias_uid,
    la.alias AS list_alias,
    lm.uid AS list_member_uid,
    m.full_name AS list_member_name,
    m.email_address AS list_member_email_address
FROM list LEFT JOIN list_member lm ON lm.list_uid=list.uid
    LEFT JOIN mailbox m ON m.uid=lm.mailbox_uid
    LEFT JOIN business b ON list.business_uid=b.uid
    LEFT JOIN list_alias la ON la.list_uid=list.uid
WHERE list.business_uid=1
ORDER BY list.full_name ASC
```

Comment: The magical solution here was to make mailbox a left-joined table as well.  By doing that, *and removing it from the WHERE clause*, everything else came through correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Question: What are the values of 'uid' from the 'list' table? Because 'uid' is not the same as 'business_uid'. What I mean is ...

If the 'list' table has this ...

'uid'     'business_uid'
1               1
2               1
3               1
4               1

Then that is the problem. You are returning the same 'busines_uid' but a different 'uid' which means it will only match the first record.

Comment: This looks promising.  The list table has 4 uid/business_uid combinations of the style [1,1],[2,1],[3,1],[4,1].  How could I approach this to get those rows returned?

Comment: Ahh in that case remove the WHERE clause or change it to check uid = 1 instead.

Comment: I only have the business_uid value to check on and there have to be 4 results. Also, would it be better to say where b.uid=1 ?